# How to resize Fancybox using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

I can't resize my fancybox, when I use ajax...
This is how my code looks like:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
   var formData = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
   formData.push({ name: this.name, value: this.value });
      $.ajax({
          type        : "POST",
          cache       : false,
          url         : "<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/kryssord-opplaster/opplasting/utfoerOppgave.php",
          data        : formData,
          success     : function(data) {
                           $.fancybox(data);
                        }
       });
     return false;
});
```

how do I resize the $.fancybox(data);?
I tried ".....$.fancybox(data, {'width': '50%', 'height': '75%'})..."

but that didn't work at all.. Thanks in advance!

#### Update:

Seems like I only had some errors in my HTML-code..
I had set `<table><form></form></table>` instead of `<form><table></table></form>..`

And somehow the way I've coded it now, if I set a stylesheet in the php-file (the url) it affects the page in the background as well.. So the best thing would be if I could get the ajax-page inside a iframe. However if I edit the fancybox-script to `..$.fancybox(data, {'type': 'iframe'});` i get a 403 error..

could someone help me modify the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, add this into html source `<div id="successContainer"></div>`

```
$("#successContainer").html(data);
$("#successContainer").fancybox({'width': '50%', 'height': '75%'});
```

Comment: I didn't get that to work. I only got the url-document to be displayed in the successContainer, and not in a fancybox. However I managed to get it to work, thanks anyway! I only have one problem left now XD (see my answer on my post)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to resize it to a certain height and width, or just have it automatically resize to fit the content?

Try throwing this into the ajax success portion:

```
$.fancybox.resize();
```

Or try:

```
$.fancybox({'width': '50%', 'height': '75%'});
```

As for the update, I'm a little unclear of what you're trying to do, could you clarify? Why do you need the iframe?